# eventtocommand for dynamically created controls silverlight mvvm light

Tags: dynamic, controls, mvvm-light, eventtrigger

I want to add a trigger to a dynamically created control but I couldn't. The event doesn't fire. This is my code.

```
    <sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="NameTemplate" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding LstRs}" 
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource RsTemplate}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Nom}" FontWeight="Bold" >
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter">
                                <gs:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Path=StateCommand}"         
       CommandParameter="{Binding Text, ElementName=TextBoxSearch, Mode=OneWay}"
                                        MustToggleIsEnabledValue="True"/>
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>

                </TextBlock>
            </sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

and the command is implemented in the view model.

Comment: Try adding a breakpoint in the OnAttached method in the EventToCommand code (must have source for MvvmLight project added to your solution) and see if the breakpoint gets hit.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, the most common error in such a case is that the command was not created - i.e. `StateCommand == null` - when the data is bound. Make sure you created the command in the constructor of you view-model.